# cannot manage reports after import from pentaho 7.1 to pentaho 9.0

Tags: linux, pentaho

I have upgraded our Pentaho 7.1 CE instalaltion to Pentaho 9.0.
What I did, was to set up new, Pentaho 9.0, and import resources from Pentaho 7.1 to Pentaho 9.0 using `import-export.sh` script that is included in penaho-server.

After export from Pentaho 7.1 and import into Pentaho 9.0, everything seemed to work just right. Reports were working properly, schedules were executed as planned. All accounts and roles been working as intended. However, when we need to manage some report file, change permission of users. We are getting this error message: `Sorry. You cannot do that right now.`

While `catalina.out` log says only: `[FileResource] Error getting system resource`.

I have obviously tried to restart pentaho server, no change. Also been trying to delete the report file and reupload it. Only reuslt is, that now I have 2 report files, both unmanageable.

I have been trying to find more about this issue on Pentaho forums and here (on stack), but have found nothing (not to mention, that its almost impossible to find anything on new Hitachi-Vantara "community site" and old Pentaho forums are closed).

Does anybody know where could be problem, or what should I check?

Comment: can you do import export through UI and check if that works.

Comment: I am not aware of the UI Import export. Can you give me hint where I could find it?

Comment: Which repository you are using ? File repo or database repo?

Comment: hibernate, quartz and jackrabbit are in postgresql database.